# How to create a react app without admin credentials in Windows?

Tags: reactjs

I am a newbie to React and I work on in a corporation where they do not give you admin credentials to your working PC but you can call IT-support and get them to type a few commands in command terminal and install the software.

So they have installed `node.js` and run a simple `npm i -g create-react-app` under administrator privileges.

But when I run `npx create-react-app my_app` without admin credentials, I fail after a long installation.

So is there anyway to download the basic react app to get started, or make IT-support write a few command lines or is it impossible to develop React without admin credentials?

Comment: Don't install create-react-app as a global package (`-g`). Then you'll find it in `node_modules/.bin/create-react-app`.

Comment: You'd better insist on giving the admin to you, or you will have to write tickets on helpdesk every time you need to install something like docker/npm packages or update env. variables. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Sergiu it worked. And for Roman you are right. I will say to them you said I should have Admin credientials.

Comment: Just call them give you the admin privilege...

Comment: I too work at a large corporation with locked-down machines, and we have limited admin privileges. You probably aren't going to get very far asking for full admin access. You are better to work with the IT/security team to figure out exactly what is failing and where so they can figure out the best approach. Yes, I get that it's frustrating. We went through a period where every `npm install` would fail after a long wait, but we've got through that and now things run smoothly without full admin

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a Linux VM (Virtual Machine). Oracle's VirtualBox is free. Your company may already allow you to load it from some central software repository. This allows you to go ahead and develop in a Sandbox that won't disrupt your company's main network. Ask your IT or Security Dept before installing and using.

Answer (score 0):

First of all removing the `-g` and installing with the local user helped. But we countinued to face challenges with all sort of corporate IT security blockades. At the end we ended up provisioning our own EC2 machine on amazon and where developing using VScode's remote SSH and we have not looked back since. So please consider this if you are on a restricted corperate PC.